# Why are my python packages not being found in Ubuntu when I use pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

I was installing packages in Python today and I noticed that whenever I used sudo apt-get install numpy (just an example), I could import numpy in python.

However, if I were to use pip install numpy, I would get an error of "No module named numpy".

I looked at the sys.path and it showed the following:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

so all my packages should be seen as they're in either `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'`. I checked.

Is there a reason this is happening and what can I do?

Comment: You have two different interpreters installed

Comment: But how? I used a fresh instance!

Comment: what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` is the output.

Comment: and `which pip`? Are you sure pip does not point to python3?